# Google Map displays locally but not when published

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have a web app that centers and zoom the continental us with custom markers that are dynamically set based on a pg query from a database. The map is displaying locally but not after I publish it to my server. I have an api key and have confirmed permissions on the google development console.

Here is the javascript:

```
function initMap() {

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 5,
      center: {lat: 39.350033, lng: -94.6500523}
    });

    // Do not actually need labels for our purposes, but the site_id is best if they are required.
    var labels = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';



    // Add some markers to the map.
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {

if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
    var arr = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
    console.log(xhr.responseText);
    if(Array.isArray(arr)){
        showMarkers(arr);
    }
}
}
xhr.open('GET', 'markers.php', true);
xhr.send();

function showMarkers(locations){
var markers = locations.map(function(location, i) {
  return new google.maps.Marker({
    position: location,
    label: labels[i % labels.length]
  });
});

var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, {imagePath: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/images/beachflag.png'});
}
  }
```

I set a restriction on the api key to *.rightmediasolutions.com/*

Here is a link to the published html:  http://www.rightmediasolutions.com/gs_chrome/map.html

Answer (score 0):

Did some research... In order for the map to fully initialize, the height and width need to be styled inline rather than on the linked stylesheet.

Comment: That isn't required, they should work from the style sheet (but the map div does need to have a size).